# Sklearn fit Features as Lists into Modell:

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification

I want to build a classification model where I want to enter the features as lists.  Is it possible to enter the features as lists?

z. B. X=[[0:300], [0:300], [0:300], [0:300]]

I have 38 features and every single feature consists of a list with 300 values.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to enter the features as lists?

Yes.

But they will wind up as an array (perhaps within a dataframe)
by the time `.fit()` sees them,
zum Beispiel:

```
>>> np.array([range(3), range(3)])
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2]])
```

or the equivalent `np.array([list(range(3)), list(range(3))])`.